# Visual Studio Load Test - Display Data Source values into Test Details

Tags: visual-studio, csv, performance-testing, load-testing

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Load Test and I have a data source CSV file that store user information.

When I run the Load Test I'm like to be able to know which test used which user from the CSV file.  Is there a way to store that information in the Test Details section or even query it from the Load Test database?  Right now, the only way for me to find out which user was used in the test is to save all test logs and check each one separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the failings of Visual Studio's load tests. There is no out-of-the-box way to collect details of test iterations, their data source values and the test outcome. The only built in method involves viewing the web test logs one at a time. That involves lots of mouse waving and mouse clicks.

One way I use is to use a `WebTestPlugin` and have the `PostWebTest` method write some details to a log (i.e. text) file.

Comment: Adrian, I found a MSDN post you made asking the same question and was able to use your code from the post to create my own log file.  Not the cleanest way to workaround it, but it will work!   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43c33e9e-4ddb-4eb8-9ebe-4bd13e2070e6/comments-are-not-being-written-to-the-test-log-from-a-web-test-plugin?forum=vstest

Comment: I am not happy with the code you found on that Microsoft forum page. It was written to demonstrate a bug in the load test software. My concern is that it opens and closes the stream for every test run. A better approach is to save the stream in a `static` which is opened once, then the plugin just writes and flushes. For safety I also think the write+flush should be protected with a `lock`.